# Javax validation on nested objects - not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

In my Spring Boot project I have two DTO's which I'm trying to validate, LocationDto and BuildingDto. The LocationDto has a nested object of type BuildingDto.

These are my DTO's:

**LocationDto**

```
public class LocationDto {

  @NotNull(groups = { Existing.class })
  @Null(groups = { New.class })
  @Getter
  @Setter
  private Integer id;

  @NotNull(groups = { New.class, Existing.class })
  @Getter
  @Setter
  private String name;

  @NotNull(groups = { New.class, Existing.class, LocationGroup.class })
  @Getter
  @Setter
  private BuildingDto building;

  @NotNull(groups = { Existing.class })
  @Getter
  @Setter
  private Integer lockVersion;

}
```

**BuildingDto**

```
public class BuildingDto {

  @NotNull(groups = { Existing.class, LocationGroup.class })
  @Null(groups = { New.class })
  @Getter
  @Setter
  private Integer id;

  @NotNull(groups = { New.class, Existing.class })
  @Getter
  @Setter
  private String name;

  @NotNull(groups = { Existing.class })
  @Getter
  @Setter
  private List<LocationDto> locations;

  @NotNull(groups = { Existing.class })
  @Getter
  @Setter
  private Integer lockVersion;

}
```

Currently, I can validate in my `LocationDto` that the properties `name` and `building` are not null, but **I can't validate the presence of the property id which is inside building**.

If I use the `@Valid` annotation on the `building` property, it would validate all of its fields, but for this case I only want to validate its `id`.

How could that be done using javax validation?

This is my controller:

```
@PostMapping
public LocationDto createLocation(@Validated({ New.class, LocationGroup.class }) @RequestBody LocationDto location) {
  // save entity here...
}
```

This is a correct request body: (should not throw validation errors)

```
{
  "name": "Room 44",
  "building": {
    "id": 1
  }
}
```

This is an incorrect request body: (must throw validation errors because the ***building id is missing***)

```
{
  "name": "Room 44",
  "building": { }
}
```

Comment: what is "ExistingClass" ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`@ConvertGroup`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/index.html?javax/validation/groups/ConvertGroup.html) from [**Bean Validation 1.1 (JSR-349)**](https://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-groupsequence-groupconversion).

Introduce a new validation group say `Pk.class`. Add it to `groups` of `BuildingDto`:

```
public class BuildingDto {

    @NotNull(groups = {Pk.class, Existing.class, LocationGroup.class})
    // Other constraints
    private Integer id;

    //
}
```

And then in `LocationDto` cascade like following:

```
@Valid
@ConvertGroup.List( {
    @ConvertGroup(from=New.class, to=Pk.class),
    @ConvertGroup(from=LocationGroup.class, to=Pk.class)
} )
// Other constraints
private BuildingDto building;
```

***Further Reading:***

[5.5. Group conversion](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-group-conversion) from Hibernate Validator reference.

Answer (score 86):

Just try adding `@valid` to collection. it would be working as per reference [hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e496)

```
  @Getter
  @Setter
  @Valid
  @NotNull(groups = { Existing.class })
  private List<LocationDto> locations;
```

Comment: This is the simple yet accurate solution!

Answer (score 27):

@Valid annotation must be added to cascade class attributes.

**LocationDTO.class**

```
public class LocationDto {

  @Valid
  private BuildingDto building;
   
  .........

}
```