# Why my model is still passing validations on empty field to the db?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

some strange issue has shown up, in the business model I use the list of addresses that cannot be empty or null, but each field in the object address cannot be null or empty either. But when I send a request with one of the fields empty, the request will pass to the repository, which shouldn't happen. Instead of passing a request, the server should return an internal server error.

Address object:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Address {
    @NotEmpty(message = "Street may not be empty")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 256)
    private String street;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Number may not be empty")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 5)
    private String number;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Postal code may not be empty")
    @Field("postal_code")
    @JsonProperty("postal_code")
    @Size(min = 5, max = 6)
    private String postalCode;

    @NotEmpty(message = "City may not be empty")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 256)
    private String city;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Province may not be empty")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 256)
    private String province;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Country may not be empty")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 256)
    private String country;
}
```

Business object which contains list of addresses:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "businesses")
public class Business {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 64)
    private String name;

    @Field("created_at")
    private Date createdAt;

    @Field("updated_at")
    private Date updatedAt;

    private Boolean active;

    @DBRef
    private User owner;

    @Valid
    private List<Address> addresses;

    public Business(String name, User owner, List<Address> addresses, Date createdAt, Date updatedAt, Boolean active) {
        this.name = name;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.addresses = addresses;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Business(String name, User owner, List<Address> addresses, Date updatedAt, Boolean active) {
        this.name = name;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.addresses = addresses;
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
        this.active = active;
    }
}
```

And in the end, service:

```java
@Override
public ResponseEntity<?> createBusiness(CreateBusinessRequest request, String token) throws RuntimeException {
    Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByUsername(jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(token.substring(7)));
    if(businessRepository.existsByName(request.getName())) {
        throw new ItemAlreadyExistsException("Business with " + request.getName() + " already exists!");
    }

    if(user.isEmpty()) {
        throw new NotFoundException("User with "+ user.get().getUsername() +" does not exist!");
    }

    if(request.getAddresses().isEmpty() || request.getAddresses() == null) {
        throw new InvalidInputException("Address is empty!");
    }

    Business business = new Business(
            request.getName(),
            user.get(),
            request.getAddresses(),
            new Date(),
            new Date(),
            true
    );

    businessRepository.save(business);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(business);
}
```

Controller:

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('MODERATOR') or hasRole('ADMIN')")
@PostMapping("/create")
public ResponseEntity<?> createBusiness(@Valid @RequestBody CreateBusinessRequest request, @RequestHeader (name="Authorization") String token) {
    return businessService.createBusiness(request, token);
}
```

CreateBusinessRequest request model

```java
@Data
public class CreateBusinessRequest {
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Valid
    private List<Address> addresses;
}
```

Request:

```json
{
    "name": "Test business",
    "addresses": [
        {
            "street": "",
            "number": "100",
            "postal_code": "84104",
            "city": "Test city",
            "province": "Test",
            "country": "Slovakia"
        }
    ]
}
```

Pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ratify</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>backend</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <json.webtoken.version>0.9.1</json.webtoken.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.22</lombok.version>
        <jakarta.xml.bind.version>2.3.2</jakarta.xml.bind.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>${json.webtoken.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakarta.xml.bind.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I hope that I explained my issue correctly.
Is there any solution to this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you imported hibernate validator dependency? do you have the @Valid annotation on the request parameter? i don't see it in the code.

Comment: I haven't imported hibernate, because of the non-relational database. In my case, I am using MongoDB. Here is updated post with controller.

Comment: Maybe the issue could be that I am directly inserting data from the controller into the constructor, without any object mappers or other things to control data that are flowing into the app.

Comment: You need `@Valid` on the `addresses` field, else validation will not propagate (this is documenten in the javax.validation specification). And make sure you have `spring-boot-starter-validation` on your classpath and not only the `javax.validation` (or worse `jakarta.validation`) api on your classpath.

Comment: I have added `@Valid` annotation to the addresses field, but still the same issue, the request passes to the repo...  About `@Valid` it is imported from `javax.validation` so I don't see the problem there...

Comment: And as stated make sure you have `spring-boot-starter-validation` as a dependency and not just `javax.validation` as an API. An API without an implementatin doesn't do anything.

Comment: Another thing is you have security annotations on your controller, which leads to proxies, which might make the `@Valid` annotation invisible. Try without the `@PreAuthorize` and see if it works, if so then explicitly add configuration to enable class proxies for the controller. Also please add the **full controller** instead of only a snippet of the method involved.

Comment: The issue is fixed. I used hibernate dependency with security validations dependency and somehow I had collisions with these two dependencies. Thank you M. Deinum for your help I would like to give the correct answer to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are missing one key dependency:

```xml
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I haven't seen this much replies, I have spring boot starter validation dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53999226/javax-validation-on-nested-objects-not-working) question I recommend adding the @Valid annotation (javax.validation.Valid) to the addresses property of the Business class. Also see the example [here](https://riptutorial.com/spring/example/30721/-valid-usage-to-validate-nested-pojos)

EDIT:
After adding the annotation you can use BindingResult for controller validation. An example would like this:

```
@PostMapping("/")
public String doSomething(@Valid @RequestBody SomeModel model, BindingResult bindingResult) 
{
   if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) 
   {
      // handle validation error
   }
}
```

Comment: I added @Valid annotation to the business DTO but still no result, request passes the service and creates the business in the database...

Comment: I see the model you a have as a controller parameter is a CreateBusinessRequest object. Is that the DTO you added the @Valid annotation to?  If so, try adding another controller parameter of type org.springframework.validation.BindingResult; and checking for a binding error with bindingResult.hasErrors() (if your BindingResult is named bindingResult).

Comment: I tried to add the BindingResult object as a parameter but still, no errors have been displayed... In the CreateBusinessRequest object, there is a valid annotation for the address object.

Answer (score -1):

To fully configure method level security you need to add the following annotation/class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
  prePostEnabled = true, 
  securedEnabled = true, 
  jsr250Enabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
}
```

This will turn on validation of your service methods. As mentioned earlier, you can add BindingResult to your controller and check for errors in the controller if needed.

Comment: Its about validation not security, so how on earth would this help.